# Bootstrap columns gone from row alignment when stretched via hover element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[See Bootply for explanation](http://www.bootply.com/XViPp7YfcC)

In my demo above, try to hover on the first box, others get affected. I expect it would be flexible like pinterest layout. I tried overflow and height thing but it doesn't solve my problem.

I wouldn't want to change the markup as it suits my case perfectly.

Comment: You need to restate your question, it makes no sense and include your code. What exactly is "overflow and height thing"? "Flexible"?

Comment: how are you supposed to keep the rows in Bootstrap if you actually decided to NOT have rows in Bootstrap? I mean, you have the .row element, but you are using a column approach rather than a row approach, so you'll need some deep math calculation to do what you want in order to move all elements in a visual "pseudo row"

Comment: @Fabio as u can see there is white and orange boxes, and I wanted the layout to be that way, if the uses of row solved my problem, I'would have used that..

Comment: if you had used a row, your problem wouldn't exist. However, I have seen your question yesterday where you wanted not to use rows and use columns, so you're in a pickle unless you reformat your UX/UI

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use Bootstrap's column reset element between pairs of boxes, and hide them for mobile:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="productWrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="productWrap"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
    <div class="clearfix hidden-xs-block"></div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="productWrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="productWrap"></div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/EdRpZJrG8v)

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

As was suggested, rows would also work. To the contrary of your comment above, you can use nested rows and not affect your orange box sidebar.

Comment: so I'm just missing this   <div class="clearfix hidden-xs-block"></div>
?

Comment: Interesting but can it be fluid like pinterest? when the first row box got hovered, the second row both of them pushed down. Can let the 3rd item (2nd row right item) stay static?

Comment: No. You'd need a JavaScript plugin for that.